# Delphi Webcam Snapshot

Tags: delphi, webcam, directshow, snapshot

I need to find a foolproof way with Delphi XE to take a snapshot using a webcam and save it as a picture file. There are many posts about this but none of them work for me. Either the code won't compile or the image is not created. The best one so far is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106706/delphi-webcam-simple-program/9107243#9107243) using VFrames. It shows the web cam video perfectly but when I try to save a snapshot to a bmp using the code below the image is blank white. I tried assigning it to a TImage with the same result. Does anyone know why this happens or have a better way to do this?

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  cam:TVideoImage;
  strlst:TStringList;
  BMP:TBitmap;
begin
  strlst := TStringList.Create ;
  cam :=TVideoImage.Create;
  cam.GetListOfDevices(strlst);
  cam.VideoStart(strlst.Strings[0]); //specify a cam by number
  //get snapshot
  BMP := TBitmap.Create;
  cam.GetBitmap(BMP);
  BMP.SaveToFile('C:\test.bmp');
  cam.VideoStop;
  BMP.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19726811/800214)?

Comment: Yes it results in a blank white bmp.

Comment: Duplicate is defined by the question, since I realized the problem with the accepted answer I added a new one there.

Comment: Yes your new solution does work @bummi. Except that it has a memory leak. I can't comment there for some reason.

Comment: I tested it without leaks using following versions: `VFrames  Version 1.6    2012-07-09 (using UGDIPlus), VSample Version 1.22`

Comment: Yes upgrading the units to the latest versions fixes the memory leaks. Thanks bummi.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should have a look a DirectX and I think you should have a look at this site :

http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample

This page offers a great way to use webcams under windows, its very reliable and allows you to set any cam property. Its all opensource, easy to use and based on native windows DirectX libraries.

Use this sample:

http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample/DirectXDelphiWebcamCapture.rar

This is a directX conversion to pascal made by michael@grizzlymotion.com

add VSample.pas and VFrames.pas to your project

```
uses  VFrames;

procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  cam:TVideoImage;
  strlst:TStringList;
begin    
   strlst := TStringList.Create ;

   cam := TVideoImage.Create;
   cam.GetListOfDevices(strlst);

   cam.SetDisplayCanvas(PaintBox1.Canvas);
   cam.VideoStart(strlst.Strings[0])    ;//specify your cam by number
end;
```

---

Or you can have a look at this : http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcam-cap/ it uses pure API calls to AVICAP32.DLL

Comment: I doubt delphibasics can provide anything reliable...

Comment: I've already tried this VFrames code. Plugging the snapshot code into the first demo now gives me a 0 byte bmp instead of a blank white bmp.

When I try to combine the sourceforge project code to only create one jpg I get a 0 byte image file.

Comment: Then try the other example

Comment: OK the sourceforge FernandoVR project code is now the best code available. If I click btnligar, btn3 then btndesligar with one frame per second I get a decent single jpg snapshot. I need this to happen all at once so I put calls to these button clicks in a new button's OnClick. Clicking that new button gives me a 0 length jpg. If I click the three buttons individually then my new button, it works. WTH

Comment: Note that I actually only have to click btnligar then my new button and it produces a valid jpg. This shows there is some sort of race condition happening.