# Delphi - Capture webcam snapshot using DirectX from a Thread

Tags: delphi, directx, webcam

Following the tips from this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071559/2205502) I created a simple application for Windows that can get a snapshot from the webcam, using DirectX library.

Now I am trying to get the same result using `thread`. Here is what I got so far:

```
  TGetWebcam = class(TThread)
  private
    FWCVideo: TVideoImage;
    FJpgShot: TJPEGImage;
    procedure OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject;
      Width, Height: Integer; DataPtr: Pointer);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TGetWebcam.Create;
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FJpgShot := TJPEGImage.Create;
  FWCVideo := TVideoImage.Create;
  FWCVideo.OnNewVideoFrame := OnNewVideoFrame;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

destructor TGetWebcam.Destroy;
begin
  FWCVideo.Free;
  FJpgShot.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.Execute;
var
  TmpLst: TStringList;
  JpgImg: TJpegImage;
begin
  TmpLst := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FWCVideo.GetListOfDevices(TmpLst);
    if TmpLst.Count <= 0 then Exit;
    if FWCVideo.VideoStart(TmpLst[0]) = 0 then
    begin
      TmpLst.Clear;
      FWCVideo.GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes(TmpLst);                          
      if TmpLst.Count <= 0 then Exit;
      FWCVideo.SetResolutionByIndex(TmpLst.Count - 1);
      JpgImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
      try
        JpgImg.Assign(FJpgShot);
        JpgImg.CompressionQuality := 50;
        JpgImg.SaveToFile('c:\test.jpg');
      finally
        JpgImg.Free;
      end;
      FWCVideo.VideoStop;
    end;
  finally
    TmpLst.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: Integer;
  DataPtr: Pointer);
begin
  FWCVideo.GetJPG(FJpgShot);  // I added this procedure "GetJPG" to VFrames.pas
end;
```

Problem is, `GetListOfDevices` always return empty when using inside `thread`.

Please, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

After many tests and debugging following `Remy Lebeau` great tips, my conclusion is that `OnNewVideoFrame` is never fired when using `TVideoImage` inside thread. So my next test was trying to get the webcam shot inside the same `execute` method that creates `TVideoImage`, after waiting for some seconds, and it worked in the first time, but next time it always get blank white images, I need to close the application and open again for it to work one more time. Here is a abstract of the code I am using:

```
procedure TGetWebcam.Execute;
var
  WCVideo: TVideoImage;
  TmpList: TStringList;
  JpgShot: TJPEGImage;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    WCVideo := TVideoImage.Create;
    try
      TmpList := TStringList.Create;
      try
        WCVideo.GetListOfDevices(TmpList);
        if TmpList.Count = 0 then Exit;
        if WCVideo.VideoStart(TmpList[0]) <> 0 then Exit;
        TmpList.Clear;
        WCVideo.GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes(TmpList);
        if TmpList.Count = 0 then Exit;
        WCVideo.SetResolutionByIndex(ScnResId);
          
        Sleep(5000);                                                                     
          
        JpgShot := TJPEGImage.Create;
        try
          WCVideo.GetJPG(JpgShot);
          JpgShot.SaveToFile('c:\test.jpg');                                                       
        finally
          JpgShot.Free;
        end;
        finally
          WCVideo.VideoStop;
        end;
      finally
        TmpList.Free;
      end;
    finally
      WCVideo.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Please, why this code works in the first time it runs but in next times always get blank white images? Thanks!

Comment: In your updated code, the calls to `WCVideo.GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes()` and `WCVideo.SetResolutionByIndex()` should be inside the `try..finally` after calling `VideoStart()`. Otherwise, you risk exiting your thread without stopping the video feed, unless the `TVideoImage` destructor handles that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectX uses ActiveX/COM interfaces.  As such, your thread's `Execute()` method needs to initialize the COM library for itself via `CoInitialize/Ex()` before accessing any COM objects.

But more importantly, you are creating and using the `TVideoImage` object across thread boundaries. Most COM objects are not designed to be used across thread boundaries, they would have to be marshaled in order to do that.  So don't use `TVideoImage` that way. Create, use, and destroy it all within the same thread (ie, inside your `Execute()` method).

Try this instead:

```pascal
type
  TGetWebcam = class(TThread)
  private
    FWCVideo: TVideoImage;
    FJpgShot: TJPEGImage;
    procedure OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: Integer; DataPtr: Pointer);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

...

uses
  Winapi.ActiveX;

constructor TGetWebcam.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FJpgShot := TJPEGImage.Create;
end;

destructor TGetWebcam.Destroy;
begin
  FJpgShot.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.Execute;
var
  TmpLst: TStringList;
  JpgImg: TJpegImage;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    FWCVideo := TVideoImage.Create;
    try
      FWCVideo.OnNewVideoFrame := OnNewVideoFrame;
      TmpLst := TStringList.Create;
      try
        FWCVideo.GetListOfDevices(TmpLst);
        if TmpLst.Count <= 0 then Exit;
        if FWCVideo.VideoStart(TmpLst[0]) <> 0 then Exit;
        try
          TmpLst.Clear;
          FWCVideo.GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes(TmpLst);                          
          if TmpLst.Count <= 0 then Exit;
          FWCVideo.SetResolutionByIndex(TmpLst.Count - 1);
          JpgImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
          try
            JpgImg.Assign(FJpgShot);
            JpgImg.CompressionQuality := 50;
            JpgImg.SaveToFile('c:\test.jpg');
          finally
            JpgImg.Free;
          end;
        finally
          FWCVideo.VideoStop;
        end;
      finally
        TmpLst.Free;
      end;
    finally
      FWCVideo.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: Integer; DataPtr: Pointer);
begin
  FWCVideo.GetJPG(FJpgShot);
end;
```

That being said, I would suggest a slightly tweaked approach - assuming the `OnNewVideoFrame` event is fired asynchronously, the thread should actually wait for the event to fire and not just assume it does, and also it should stop the video capture before using the captured JPG, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.SyncObjs;

type
  TGetWebcam = class(TThread)
  private
    FJpgShot: TJPEGImage;
    FJpgShotReady: TEvent;
    procedure OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: Integer; DataPtr: Pointer);
    function GetJpgShot: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

...

uses
  Winapi.ActiveX;

constructor TGetWebcam.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FJpgShot := TJPEGImage.Create;
  FJpgShotReady := TEvent.Create;
end;

destructor TGetWebcam.Destroy;
begin
  FJpgShot.Free;
  FJpgShotReady.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.Execute;
var
  JpgImg: TJpegImage;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    if not GetJpgShot() then Exit;
    JpgImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      JpgImg.Assign(FJpgShot);
      JpgImg.CompressionQuality := 50;
      JpgImg.SaveToFile('c:\test.jpg');
    finally
      JpgImg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;

function TGetWebcam.GetJpgShot: Boolean;
var
  TmpLst: TStringList;
  WCVideo: TVideoImage;
begin
  Result := False;
  WCVideo := TVideoImage.Create;
  try
    WCVideo.OnNewVideoFrame := OnNewVideoFrame;
    TmpLst := TStringList.Create;
    try
      WCVideo.GetListOfDevices(TmpLst);
      if TmpLst.Count < 1 then Exit;
      if WCVideo.VideoStart(TmpLst[0]) <> 0 then Exit;
      try
        TmpLst.Clear;
        WCVideo.GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes(TmpLst);
        if TmpLst.Count < 1 then Exit;
        WCVideo.SetResolutionByIndex(TmpLst.Count - 1);
        Result := FJpgShotReady.WaitFor(5000) = wrSignaled;
      finally
        WCVideo.VideoStop;
      end;
    finally
      TmpLst.Free;
    end;
  finally
    WCVideo.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: Integer; DataPtr: Pointer);
begin
  TVideoImage(Sender).GetJPG(FJpgShot);
  FJpgShotReady.SetEvent;
end;
```

**UPDATE:** you might need to add a message loop to your thread in order for the `OnNewVideoFrame` event to fire correctly, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Winapi.Windows;

type
  TGetWebcam = class(TThread)
  private
    FJpgShot: TJPEGImage;
    FJpgShotReady: Boolean;
    procedure OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: Integer; DataPtr: Pointer);
    function GetJpgShot: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

...

uses
  Winapi.ActiveX;

constructor TGetWebcam.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FJpgShot := TJPEGImage.Create;
end;

destructor TGetWebcam.Destroy;
begin
  FJpgShot.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.Execute;
var
  JpgImg: TJpegImage;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    if not GetJpgShot() then Exit;
    JpgImg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      JpgImg.Assign(FJpgShot);
      JpgImg.CompressionQuality := 50;
      JpgImg.SaveToFile('c:\test.jpg');
    finally
      JpgImg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;

function TGetWebcam.GetJpgShot: Boolean;
var
  TmpLst: TStringList;
  WCVideo: TVideoImage;
  Msg: TMSG;
begin
  Result := False;
  WCVideo := TVideoImage.Create;
  try
    WCVideo.OnNewVideoFrame := OnNewVideoFrame;
    TmpLst := TStringList.Create;
    try
      WCVideo.GetListOfDevices(TmpLst);
      if TmpLst.Count < 1 then Exit;
      if WCVideo.VideoStart(TmpLst[0]) <> 0 then Exit;
      try
        TmpLst.Clear;
        WCVideo.GetListOfSupportedVideoSizes(TmpLst);
        if TmpLst.Count < 1 then Exit;
        WCVideo.SetResolutionByIndex(TmpLst.Count - 1);
        FJpgShotReady := False;
        while (not FJpgShotReady) and GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
        begin
          TranslateMessage(Msg);
          DispatchMessage(Msg);
        end;
        Result := FJpgShotReady;
      finally
        WCVideo.VideoStop;
      end;
    finally
      TmpLst.Free;
    end;
  finally
    WCVideo.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TGetWebcam.OnNewVideoFrame(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: Integer; DataPtr: Pointer);
begin
  TVideoImage(Sender).GetJPG(FJpgShot);
  FJpgShotReady := True;
end;
```

Comment: Mr. Lebeau, I tried your first solution with a "virtual" webcam (`DroidCam`) and worked just fine, but unfortunately didn't work with a real webcam. With a real webcam it always gets blank white shots, and now I understood what you mean with "wait for the event to fire and not just assume it does". So I tried to implement the second solution, despite I never worked with `TEvent` before, but the `FJpgShotReady.WaitFor(5000) = wrSignaled` always return `False`. Please, do you have any idea what's going on? I sincerely have no idea...

Comment: Chances are, the `OnNewVideoFrame` event is likely fired in the same thread that starts the video capture. In which case, the `WaitFor()` would block that event from firing. You can try setting the `UseCOMWait` parameter of the `TEvent` constructor to True (`FJpgShotReady := TEvent.Create(True);`) so that `WaitFor()` will still pump internal COM messages while waiting for the `TEvent` to be signaled.

Comment: Mr. Lebeau, I understood your idea about the issue, but setting `UseCOMWait` to True didn't solve. I am doing some more tests / debuging and let you know any news. If you have any other idea please let me know. Thank you so much!

Comment: Then you might need a standard message loop, using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to wait on both the `TEvent` and the thread's message queue at the same time, pumping messages with `PeekMessage()`+`DispatchMessage()` if they arrive.

Comment: Mr. Lebeau, after many tests my conclusion is that `OnNewVideoFrame` event is never fired when using `TVideoImage` inside thread. So I tried getting the webcam shot `GetJPG(JpgShot)` inside the same `execute` method that creates `TVideoImage`, after waiting for some secs, and it worked in the first time, but never again (only gives me blank white images). I also researched about `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` but sincerely my IQ isn't enough for understanding this subjects :) I will update the question with my new code, will be glad if you could update the answer with any other idea. Thank you!

Comment: The original `TVideoImage` example you based your code on operates asynchronously in the main UI thread, but it doesn't use the `OnNewVideoFrame` event for its work. If the underlying DirectX COM object is apartment-threaded, it needs a message loop to fire events. The only difference between a UI thread and your worker thread is a message loop. When you say "after many tests", what EXACTLY did you try? As I said earlier, you may need to add a message loop to your thread, so did you try that?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a message loop example.

Comment: Mr. Lebeau, I never worked with message loop before. I did some research about this subject, made tests in a different application, but it's very complex and can't understand yet. So my next step was debugging the main app for understanding whats was happening, then I realized `OnNewVideoFrame` was never fired. My supposition was that, once the event is never fired, no matter what we do, even using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, would not work. Well, I see you included an update, I will try to implement it tomorrow (it's late here). Thank you again!

Comment: If the original code does not fire the `OnNewVideoFrame` event, even when used in the main UI thread, then either `TVideoImage` is broken to begin with, `OnNewVideoFrame` is not implemented, or you are simply using it incorrectly (for instance, maybe `VideoStart()` is not meant to fire `OnNewVideoFrame` at all, ie because the original code was using `TVideoImage.SetDisplayCanvas()` instead). Without any documentation or source code for `TVideoImage`, it is difficult to diagnose your issue.

Comment: Mr. Lebeau, your last update is working perfecly, thanks! I will now research about message loop to try to understand what you did. I'd like to add that `SetResolutionByIndex` must be called after `VideoStart`, otherwise will throught an Access Violation error. Thank you very much!

Comment: "*I will now research about message loop*" - see [Message and Message Queue Overviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/message-and-message-queue-overviews) and [Single-Threaded Apartments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/single-threaded-apartments). "*`SetResolutionByIndex` must be called after `VideoStart`*" - that seems like an odd requirement, but OK. I have updated my examples to show that.

Comment: I wish you nothing but sucess! Thank you!